# php previous months years

Tags: php, sql

I am using this code to access previous months data. However when it gets to January it stops and doesn't continue to December of the previous year. How would I adjust this code to continue back to the previous months AND years.

```
    $prev_date = date('Y-m', strtotime($date .' -1 month'));
```

Comment: Don't use `strtotime()` for date math and manipulation. Use `DateTime()` and its related classes which are much better suited for these things.

Comment: It was used like this... <a href="?dates=<?php echo $prev_date ?>">Previous</a> I'm just learning PHP code. I am very new at it. Somebody helped me with this part. I was just a school project I'm trying to finish.

Comment: @designaire   try it:- <?php

  $month = date('m');
  $year = date('Y');
  $last_month = $month-1%12;
  echo ($last_month==0?($year-1):$year)."-".($last_month==0?'12':$last_month);

?>

Comment: It didn't work. I'm not sure the entire page done the correct way and I might have to fix it. If I can get it to work, I'll let you know. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using next and previous button that was posted for use with a calendar. It's a great calendar and easy to use.

https://davidwalsh.name/php-event-calendar

```
$month = (int) (!empty($_GET['month']) ? $_GET['month'] : date('m'));
$year = (int)  (!empty($_GET['year']) ? $_GET['year'] : date('Y'));

/* "next month" control */
$next_month_link = '<a href="?month='.($month != 12 ? $month + 1 : 
1).'&year='.($month != 12 ? $year : $year + 1).'" class="control">Next Month 
>></a>';

/* "previous month" control */
$previous_month_link = '<a href="?month='.($month != 1 ? $month - 1 : 
12).'&year='.($month != 1 ? $year : $year - 1).'" class="control"><<    
Previous Month</a>';

/* bringing the controls together */
$controls = '<form 
method="get">'.$select_month_control.$select_year_control.' <input 
type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" />      '.$previous_month_link.'     
'.$next_month_link.' </form>';

echo $controls;
```